# How do you correctly handle the hash/pound/number (#) sign in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this website where users can enter stable names to compete in games against other members.  Usually it's fine as I can just escape or use addslashes to handle apostrophes and other such characters.  What I am having an issue with is when users use a hash/pound/number sign in the stable name like the first example below or a bunch of special characters like the second example below...

```
#a new rising
ΔMi−1 = −αΣn=1NDi[n][Σj∈C{i}Fji[n - 1] + Fexti[[n-1]]
```

When this goes over as part of a url to a second page and the stable is a appended to the URL to be used as a GET variable to pull details from the database, nothing is returned.  I have tried using urlencode, rawurlencode, and percent encoding on the $stable variable as is suggested in other questions on this site but nothing seems to work.  Below is a sample of the code that has the issue...

Referring URL --- mydomain.com/stable.php?stable=#a new rising&season=59

Code for stable.php...

```
$stable = addslashes($_GET["stable"]);
$season = $_GET['season'];

echo $stable;

$sql = "SELECT total, wins, loss, ties FROM History_Stables WHERE stable = '$stable' AND season = '$season'";
$res = $link->query($sql);
$arr = $res->fetch_array();

$pts = $arr[total];
$w = $arr[wins];
$l = $arr[loss];
$t = $arr[ties];
```

And so on.  What exactly am I missing here to get the hash/pound/number sign to be properly encoded as %23?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: You are so right Quentin, sorry.  I did read those questions you provided as duplicates but I must have read it too quickly since it's late at night.  Thanks again as I see my error.